# How to add an incremental counter to grouped rows, resetting the counter each time a variable changes

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a **PostgreSQL** table containing: person_identifier, period_identifier, status

```
 person | period | status 
 -------+--------+--------
   Bob  |   Jan  | new    
   Bob  |   Feb  | retained    
   Bob  |   Mar  | retained 
   Bob  |   Apr  | dormant 
   Bob  |   May  | dormant 
   Bob  |   Jun  | resurected 
   Bob  |   Jul  | retained
   Bob  |   Agu  | dormant
   Jim  |   Jan  | new
   Jim  |   Feb  | dormant
   Jim  |   Mar  | dormant
   Jim  |   Apr  | dormant 
   Jim  |   May  | dormant
   Jim  |   Jun  | resurected
   Jim  |   Jul  | dormant
   Jim  |   Agu  | resurected
```

What I need is to include a `counter` grouping by `person, status`, with the restriction that the counter needs to restart down to 1 whenever the status changes.

I tried the following query, but this doesn't `reset` the counter down to 1 whenever a status changes:

```
SELECT
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY person, status ORDER BY period) AS wrong_counter
FROM
    my_table
```

Here's the difference of my query and what I actually need; `* stands for wrong value`:

```
 person | period |    status   | wrong_counter | needed_counter
 -------+--------+-------------+ --------------+---------------
   Bob  |   Jan  | new         |      1        |       1       
   Bob  |   Feb  | retained    |      1        |       1       
   Bob  |   Mar  | retained    |      2        |       2       
   Bob  |   Apr  | dormant     |      1        |       1       
   Bob  |   May  | dormant     |      2        |       2       
   Bob  |   Jun  | resurected  |      1        |       1       
   Bob  |   Jul  | retained    |      3*       |       1       
   Bob  |   Agu  | dormant     |      3*       |       1       
   Jim  |   Jan  | new         |      1        |       1       
   Jim  |   Feb  | dormant     |      1        |       1       
   Jim  |   Mar  | dormant     |      2        |       2       
   Jim  |   Apr  | dormant     |      3        |       3       
   Jim  |   May  | dormant     |      4        |       4       
   Jim  |   Jun  | resurected  |      1        |       1       
   Jim  |   Jul  | dormant     |      5*       |       1       
   Jim  |   Agu  | resurected  |      2*       |       1
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: I can't get the logic behind what you want..

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i did some normalisation :

```
person -> person_fk,
period -> period_int, Jan = 1 ...
status -> status_fk
```

and use as basetable : public.tbl_test

then i do some calculations: first get the status in the line before the actual line and is it a status_change or not.
make a help_partition and then get the row_number over the help_partition.

```
with temp_base_data as 
(
select
 *,
lag(status_fk,1,-1) over(ORDER BY person_fk, period_int) as status_before,
case
when lag(status_fk,1,-1)  over(ORDER BY person_fk, period_int) = status_fk and  lag(person_fk ,1,-1) over(ORDER BY person_fk, period_int) = person_fk 
    then 0
else 1
end as status_change
from public.tbl_test
order by person_fk, period_int
),
temp_partition  AS
(
select 
*,
sum(status_change) over ( order by  person_fk, period_int  RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as help_partition
from temp_base_data
order by person_fk, period_int
)

select
 * ,
row_number() over (PARTITION by help_partition order by person_fk, period_int) as counter
from temp_partition 
order by id
```

and result in : (last row is the counter you need)

```
person  period  status  id  period_int  person_fk   status_fk   status_before   status_change   help_partition  counter
   Bob     Jan   new        1   1   1   1   -1  1   1   1
   Bob     Feb   retained   2   2   1   2   1   1   2   1
   Bob     Mar   retained   3   3   1   2   2   0   2   2
   Bob     Apr   dormant    4   4   1   3   2   1   3   1
   Bob     May   dormant    5   5   1   3   3   0   3   2
   Bob     Jun   resurected 6   6   1   4   3   1   4   1
   Bob     Jul   retained   7   7   1   2   4   1   5   1
   Bob     Agu   dormant    8   8   1   3   2   1   6   1
   Jim     Jan   new        9   1   2   1   3   1   7   1
   Jim     Feb   dormant    10  2   2   3   1   1   8   1
   Jim     Mar   dormant    11  3   2   3   3   0   8   2
   Jim     Apr   dormant    12  4   2   3   3   0   8   3
   Jim     May   dormant    13  5   2   3   3   0   8   4
   Jim     Jun   resurected 14  6   2   4   3   1   9   1
   Jim     Jul   dormant    15  7   2   3   4   1   10  1
   Jim     Agu   resurected 16  8   2   4   3   1   11  1
```